# 404 when using /interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/search?$page=X&$pageSize=X REST API route

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to get the number of entries in a journey. I am using the `/interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/search?$page=X&$pageSize=X` endpoint and am getting a 404 error in Postman. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you doing a GET?

Comment: Yes I am. Should I be doing POST?

Comment: what is the complete endpoint you are hitting?

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing a `POST` to `/interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/search` - just tried and it worked without any problems.

This is an unofficial endpoint, so it's not possible to point to any documentation, but in case you have any doubts about the routes and methods available, here is the current [discovery document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/restDiscovery.html) with the full list:

```json
{
    "methods": {
        "discovery": {
            "path": "rest",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Returns discovery document",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "postInteraction": {
            "path": "interactions",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Create or save an interaction",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "updateInteraction": {
            "path": "interactions",
            "httpMethod": "put",
            "description": "Update an interaction version",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "updateInteractionByKey": {
            "path": "interactions/key:{key}",
            "httpMethod": "put",
            "description": "Update an interaction version",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "updateInteractionById": {
            "path": "interactions/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "put",
            "description": "Update an interaction version",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "publishInteractionById": {
            "path": "interactions/publishAsync/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Publish an interaction version asynchronously",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "publishInteractionByKey": {
            "path": "interactions/publishAsync/key:{key}",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Publish an interaction version asynchronously",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "publishStatus": {
            "path": "interactions/publishStatus/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Check the status of a publication",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "validateInteractionById": {
            "path": "interactions/validateAsync/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Validate an interaction version asynchronously",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "validateInteractionByKey": {
            "path": "interactions/validateAsync/key:{key}",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Validate an interaction version asynchronously",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "validateStatus": {
            "path": "interactions/validateStatus/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Check the status of a validation",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "stop": {
            "path": "interactions/stop/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Stops a running interaction.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "stopByKey": {
            "path": "interactions/stop/key:{key}",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Stops a running interaction.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "stopAsyncById": {
            "path": "interactions/stopAsync/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Stops a running interaction asynchronously.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "stopAsyncByKey": {
            "path": "interactions/stopAsync/key:{key}",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Stops a running interaction asynchronously.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getGoalStatistics": {
            "path": "goalstatistics/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve goal statistics for an interaction",
            "parameters": {
                "id": "String id of the interaction"
            }
        },
        "postGoalStatistics": {
            "path": "goalstatistics/clear/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Clear goal statistics for an interaction",
            "parameters": {
                "id": "String id of the interaction"
            }
        },
        "getInteraction": {
            "path": "interactions/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve an interaction.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getInteractionSummary": {
            "path": "interactions/{id}/summary",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieves summarized data for a journey (across all versions). Activity counts are for active activities only.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "deleteInteraction": {
            "path": "interactions/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "delete",
            "description": "Delete an interaction.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "deleteInteractionByKey": {
            "path": "interactions/key:{key}",
            "httpMethod": "delete",
            "description": "Delete an interaction.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getInteractionCollection": {
            "path": "interactions",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve a collection of interactions.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getWaitStatistics": {
            "path": "waitstatistics/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve wait activity counts for an interaction",
            "parameters": {
                "id": "String id of the interaction"
            }
        },
        "searchJourneyHistory": {
            "path": "interactions/journeyhistory/search",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Search for contact history",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getJourneyHistoryFilter": {
            "path": "interactions/journeyhistory/filter",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Get the list of unique journeys, activity types and status for given criteria",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getJourneyHistorySummary": {
            "path": "interactions/journeyhistory/summary",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Get summary for all journeys",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getDefinitionLog": {
            "path": "interactions/definitionlogs/search",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Retrieve a collection of definition logs.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "downloadJourneyHistoryPost": {
            "path": "interactions/journeyhistory/download",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Download Journey history",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "downloadJourneyHistoryGet": {
            "path": "interactions/journeyhistory/download",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Download Journey history",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getContactKey": {
            "path": "interactions/journeyhistory/contactkey",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Search history for contact",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getSummaryByActivity": {
            "path": "interactions/{definitionId}/activities/{activityId}/summary",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Get execution summary by activity and definition",
            "parameters": {
                "definitionID": "Definition Id",
                "activityId": "Activity Id"
            }
        },
        "getJourneyHistoryTimeSeries": {
            "path": "interactions/journeyhistory/timeSeries",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Get timeSeries for all journeys",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getActivityTimeSeries": {
            "path": "interactions/{definitionId}/activities/{activityId}/timeseries",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Get execution time series by activity and definition",
            "parameters": {
                "definitionID": "Definition Id",
                "activityId": "Activity Id"
            }
        },
        "getWaitSummaryByActivity": {
            "path": "interactions/{definitionId}/activities/{activityId}/waitexpire/summary",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Get wait summary by activity and definition",
            "parameters": {
                "definitionID": "Definition Id",
                "activityId": "Activity Id"
            }
        },
        "getActivityWaitTimeSeries": {
            "path": "interactions/{definitionId}/activities/{activityId}/waitexpire/timeseries",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Get wait time series by activity and definition",
            "parameters": {
                "definitionID": "Definition Id",
                "activityId": "Activity Id"
            }
        },
        "getTriggerStatistics": {
            "path": "triggerstats/{eventDefinitionID}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve trigger statistics",
            "parameters": {
                "eventDefinitionID": "Event definition Id"
            }
        },
        "getTriggerStatisticsByJourney": {
            "path": "triggerstats/{eventDefinitionID}/{definitionID}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve trigger statistics by Journey",
            "parameters": {
                "eventDefinitionID": "Event definition Id",
                "definitionID": "Definition Id"
            }
        },
        "createTriggerTest": {
            "path": "interactions/triggerTest/{eventDefinitionId}",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Create a trigger test",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "updateTriggerTest": {
            "path": "interactions/triggerTest/{eventDefinitionId}",
            "httpMethod": "put",
            "description": "Update a trigger test",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "deleteTriggerTest": {
            "path": "interactions/triggerTest/{eventDefinitionId}",
            "httpMethod": "delete",
            "description": "Delete a trigger test",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "postEventDefinition": {
            "path": "eventDefinitions",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Create an event definition",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "updateEventDefinitionById": {
            "path": "eventDefinitions/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "put",
            "description": "Update an event definition by ID",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "updateEventDefinitionByKey": {
            "path": "eventDefinitions/key:{key}",
            "httpMethod": "put",
            "description": "Update an event definition by key",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getEventDefinitionByKey": {
            "path": "eventDefinitions/key:{key}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Get an event definition by key",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getEventDefinitionById": {
            "path": "eventDefinitions/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Get an event definition by id",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getEventDefinitionCollection": {
            "path": "eventDefinitions",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve a collection of  event definitions.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "deleteEventDefinitionById": {
            "path": "eventDefinitions/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "delete",
            "description": "Delete an event definition by id",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "deleteEventDefinitionByKey": {
            "path": "eventDefinitions/key:{key}",
            "httpMethod": "delete",
            "description": "Delete an event definition by key",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "postInteractionActivityEvents": {
            "path": "events/activityResult",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Post an async activity result",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "postInteractionsEvents": {
            "path": "events",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Post an event to interactions",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getHistory": {
            "path": "history",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve a collection of history.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getAuditLogById": {
            "path": "interactions/{id}/audit/{action}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve a collection of Audit logs.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getAuditLogByKey": {
            "path": "interactions/key:{key}/audit/{action}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve a collection of Audit logs.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getDeveloperLogs": {
            "path": "developerLogs",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve a collection of developer logs by member id.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "isActivityLogComingViaKafka": {
            "path": "isActivityLogComingViaKafka/{definitionID}/{contactKey}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "To verify that activity log coming via kafka",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "isDefinitionLogComingViaKafka": {
            "path": "isDefinitionLogComingViaKafka/{definitionID}/{contactKey}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "To verify that definition log coming via kafka",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getJourneySummaryCounts": {
            "path": "journeys/{id}/versions/{version}/summary/counts",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve journey Summary Counts.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getJourneySummaryContactsByEventType": {
            "path": "journeys/{id}/versions/{version}/summary/contacts/{type}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve journey Summary Contacts.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getJourneySummaryContacts": {
            "path": "journeys/{id}/versions/{version}/summary/contacts/{type}/{status}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve journey Summary Contacts.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getDefinitionTemplate": {
            "path": "definitionTemplates/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve a Definition Template",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getDefinitionTemplateCollection": {
            "path": "definitionTemplates",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve Definition Template collection",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "postDefinitionTemplate": {
            "path": "definitionTemplates",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Create an interaction definition template ",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "updateDefinitionTemplate": {
            "path": "definitionTemplates/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "put",
            "description": "Update an interaction definition template ",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "pauseInteractionById": {
            "path": "interactions/pause/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Pause an interaction by DefinitionId ",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "pauseInteractionByKey": {
            "path": "interactions/pause/key:{key}",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Pause an interaction by Key ",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getInteractionStatusById": {
            "path": "interactions/status/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Get status of an interaction by DefinitionId ",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getInteractionStatusByKey": {
            "path": "interactions/status/key:{key}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Get status of an interaction by Key ",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "resumeInteractionById": {
            "path": "interactions/resume/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Resume an interaction by DefinitionId ",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "resumeInteractionByKey": {
            "path": "interactions/resume/key:{key}",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Resume an interaction by Key ",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "contactExit": {
            "path": "interactions/contactexit",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Accepts list of contacts for contact exit processing",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "contactExitStatus": {
            "path": "interactions/contactexit/status",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Accepts list of contacts for returning contact exit status",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getSimulationContacts": {
            "path": "simulation/contacts",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve a random sample of DE contacts for the provided eventDefinitionId",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getSimulation": {
            "path": "simulation/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Retrieve an existing Simulation object",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "StartSimulation": {
            "path": "simulation/",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Initiates a simulation based on the journey under test and the test configuration provided in the request body",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "DeleteSimulation": {
            "path": "simulation/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "delete",
            "description": "Deletes the simulation entities and stops and deletes all related test journeys",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "CreateTransactionalMessage": {
            "path": "interactions/transactional/create",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Creates a new Transaction Send for the provided Journey DefinitionId",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "PauseTransactionalMessage": {
            "path": "interactions/transactional/pause",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Updates status to InActive for the Transactional Send associated with the provided Journey DefinitionId",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "ClearQueueForTransactionalMessage": {
            "path": "interactions/transactional/clearQueue",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Clear queue for the Transactional Send associated with the provided Journey DefinitionId",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "ResumeTransactionalMessage": {
            "path": "interactions/transactional/resume",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Updates status to Active for the Transactional Send associated with the provided Journey DefinitionId",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "AssociateCategoryWithDefinitions": {
            "path": "interactions/categories/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Assigns a categoryId to the DefinitionInfo for a list of DefinitionIds",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "GetCategoryDefinitionCounts": {
            "path": "interactions/categories/{id}/counts",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Returns the number of child categories and their journey counts by status",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "DeleteCategoryAndDefinitions": {
            "path": "interactions/categories/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "delete",
            "description": "Deletes a journey category and its associated journeys",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getContactMembershipByKey": {
            "path": "interactions/contactMembership",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Accepts list of contacts and returns mapping between contacts and active/paused journeys.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "GetDashboardUserConfig": {
            "path": "dashboard/config",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Get the dashboard configuration for the given user",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "SaveDashboardUserConfig": {
            "path": "dashboard/config",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Save a new dashboard configuration for the given user",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "ActivityAdHocExecute": {
            "path": "activity/execute",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Ad Hoc execute an activity via test harness",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "ActivitySetupTest": {
            "path": "activity/setup/test",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "description": "Ad Hoc execute an activity to test activity setup and instance creation.",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "ABnTestGetDetails": {
            "path": "abntest/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Get ABnTest activity details by Activity Id",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "ABnTestUpdate": {
            "path": "abntest/{id}",
            "httpMethod": "patch",
            "description": "Update ABnTest activity details by Activity Id",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "getEngineSettings": {
            "path": "engine-settings",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Returns engine settings",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "SalesCloudEvents": {
            "path": "SalesCloudEvents",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Returns published list of SalesCloud Events",
            "parameters": {}
        },
        "SalesCloudEventsCDC": {
            "path": "SalesCloudEvents/CDC",
            "httpMethod": "get",
            "description": "Returns published list of SalesCloud Events using CDC",
            "parameters": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not saying this answer is wrong, but `POST` is definitely an incorrect verb for an endpoint that runs a search.

Comment: @AdrianLarson please see the discovery document quoted above, as weird as it is, this search uses post. It’s an undocumented endpoint, though, so I wouldn’t use it for building any permanent solutions.

Comment: Like I said, I'm casting aspersions on the design, not your documentation of it here.